# Error causing "Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null "?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to give the img children of a div with the id of "superbgimage" a class of "fullSize," but I'm returning this error. What is the issue?

Here is my script:

```
var fullSize = document.getElementById("superbgimage");
var myImgItems = fullSize.getElementsByTagName("img");
myImgItems.setAttribute("class","fullSize");
```

HTML - Live Code

```
<div id="superbgimage" style="overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top:0px; left: 0px; display:block;">
<img src="Artwork/art23.jpg" rel="13" style="position: absolute; width: 1281px; height:    949px; left: -269px; top: 0px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please, send Your html

Comment: Either a) there's no `#superbgimage` element, or b) you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready before running this.

Comment: Also, `myImgItems` is a *list* of nodes.  You can't call `setAttribute` on it.  You need to loop over it and call `setAttribute` on each element.

Comment: I was wondering about that, because the <img> tags are created by JS. Where can I put my code as to make it happen after the DOM catches up? Also how would that be done? Looping it over and calling it, that is? Or is there a better way to do it all?

Comment: @Zartect: How are your `<img>` tags being created?  Why can't the class be added when they are created?

Comment: I am a beginner, if that, and I'm struggling to decipher the code. I am basically trying to make my Images take up 100% of the screen in a slideshow. The code it is currently using is basing size off of the browser and I can't figure out how to change it without breaking it as it is complex (to me).

Comment: Note that your img tag isn't closed. If your document is XHTML, this is invalid, and should look like <img/>

Comment: It would also be in your interest to learn jQuery. It has its pros and cons, but it will make JavaScript a little bit easier for you . When you can fully manipulate jQuery, then it can be advantageous to learn "vanilla" JavaScript

Comment: Yeah. Right now my JS knowledge is just to the extent of Lynda.com's "JavaScript Essential Training" I normally do close my img tags, but these were made by a third party's JS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through the image elements in the «myImgItems» object (it's not an actual array, it's a NodeList).

Try this.

```
var fullSize = document.getElementById("superbgimage");
var myImgItems = fullSize.getElementsByTagName("img");

var i = myImgItems.length;

// Loop over the images and set the class
while(i--) {
  myImgItems[i].setAttribute('class', 'fullSize');
}
```

Comment: Returned the same error as the original question states. I'd love to solve this because to make do I did some really sloppy code and gave the rel value styling instead of managing to give them a class to style.